# Only way i can get my php sites to run is clear cache and history

Tags: php, linux, apache, codeigniter

I have multiple sites that are built using php with codeigniter framework(apache webserver, redhat linux ec2 and postgres db), they just stop loading and the only way they would come back up is if i clear cache and history. These sites are visited very frequently(every 2-3 mins) throughout the day by about 50 people. Any suggestions as to what is causing this or where to look for a solution. Code igniter does clear out sessions after 7200s.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Define "stop loading" ?

Comment: Clearly a session related issue?

Comment: @deg the site just tries to load and shows a blank page

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the session timeout is set to 7200ms which is about 3 hours. And the code has sess_destroy in  controllers where ever needed

Comment: @BigB: A session stores information. This information can be used by your code. Your code might encounter an error while using this information. You might not have enabled error reporting. You will get a blank page. You clear the cache and the whole process starts again.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i have error reporting on as well. Dont see any errors in the logs either. Also just clearing cache doesnt load it, have to clear history along with it, which makes no sense

Comment: If your sites were working and then just stopped, that usually points to the host (but I guess you could be hosting your own websites). If these sites are hosted by somebody else, you should contact them. Hosts will often make changes that break my websites, and I've had good success getting my sites back up and running by contacting them.

Comment: @BigB: Hmm, OK, and only clearing the history is also not enough to make it work again? In most browsers there's a mode in which the website cannot access the history. Sometimes called 'incognito' or 'privacy' mode, if you use that, what happens?

Comment: @BigB Check your websites error.log file, you might find some error that will give you an insight that will fix the errors.

Comment: @BrianGottier we host our own sites. So host is out of the question

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Havent tried the incognito approach yet, since most of the people that use these sites are not familiar with that feature. I just cant figure out what else can cause this

Comment: @LasVegasCoder No errors at all.

Comment: @BigB - you said above that timeout is set to 7200ms - is that correct? If so, that's 7.2 seconds rather than three hours.

Comment: @slothluvchunk sorry i meant 7200s

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think there's much we can do to help. We cannot replicate your problem. Good luck hunting it down.

Comment: Just my way of thinking, but if I had multiple websites and they all stopped working at once, then it's a problem with the server. If all of the error logs point to nothing (error reporting fully enabled), then I'd set up the most limited app I could to reproduce the error, and try some line by line debugging. If all else fails, and if these websites are critical (and were mine), then I'd probably be setting up a new server, and transferring the content over.

Comment: @BrianGottier each site is on its own individual server but they connect to a common db.

Comment: @BigB, when you figure it out please come back and let us know. It is interesting, and I'm curious what you will find and/or do.

Comment: @BrianGottier yes will do, trying to run some apache tests to see what is happening